# error: parse error before "double" (cygwin)

Tags: java, c, arrays, java-native-interface, cygwin

So this is the code I am using:
Test.java:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SumLib");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        double[] arr = new double[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            arr[i] = rand.nextDouble();
        }
        NativeMethods.sumOfArr(arr);
}
}
```

NativeMethods.java:

```
public static native double sumOfArr(double[] arr);
```

NativeMethods.c:

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_NativeMethods_sumOfArr(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jdoubleArray arr) {
    return sumOfArr(double *arr);
}
```

NativeMethods.h is generated by "javah NativeMethods" in cygwin.

sum.c:

```
double sumOfArr(double* arr) {
    int i;
    double sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum =+ arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

sum.h:

```
double sumOfArr(double *arr);
```

The problem appears when I'm trying to compile/make the SumLib.dll in cygwin and it throws me this error:

```
$ gcc -Wl,-add-stdcall-alias -mno-cygwin -shared -I"/cygdrive/c/jdk1.7.0_09/include" -I"/cygdrive/c/jdk1.7.0_09/include/win32" -o SumLib.dll sum.c NativeMethods.c
NativeMethods.c: In function `Java_NativeMethods_sumOfArr':
NativeMethods.c:19: error: parse error before "double"
```

I am stuck here trying to get this work for several hours...
What can be wrong?

Comment: Try `return sumOfArr(arr);`. You mustn't put the type in the call. Or possibly `return sumOfArr((double *)arr);` you want a cast?

Comment: Not an answer on your question but your loop in `main` is from `0` to `11`. This will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in runtime.

Comment: Where is line 19 of the NativeMethods.c file?

Comment: A typo use `+=` instead of `=+`

Comment: Now I just have seen that, even the array it's created properly, it is sent to the NativeMethod and sum.c, but when it comes back to the main class and I'm trying to display the sum of the array, it totally shows random numbers. I even tried to put sum = arr[4]; (an element). But it doesn't show the same element as the array's fourth element. Only random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as it won't compile

```
return sumOfArr(double *arr);
```

or even this

```
return sumOfArr((double *)arr);
```

as `jdoubleArray` is not a `double *`, it has a header for a start.

You need to use the helper method Java provides to access the elements of this array.

Comment: What is this helper method that Java provides to access the elements of this array?

Comment: Didn't remember off the top of my head so had to google `jdoubleArray` and the method you want is `double * data = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(*arr, NULL);
`